# PInvoke Unbalances the stack

Tags: stack, pinvoke

I have a c++ function to be exported as a .dll to use:

```
static __declspec(dllexport) void DiagEncrypt(
    UCHAR              * ptrDataByte, 
    size_t               numBytes, 
    ACCESS_LEVEL         accLevel);
void DiagnosticCrypto::DiagEncrypt(UCHAR * ptrDataByte, size_t numBytes, ACCESS_LEVEL accLevel)
```

And I import it in my C# program:

```
[DllImport("DiagnosticCryptoDll.dll", EntryPoint = "?DiagEncrypt@DiagnosticCrypto@DiagnosticCryptoDll@@SAXPAEIW4ACCESS_LEVEL@12@@Z", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern void DiagEncrypt(
    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] data,
    IntPtr  data,
    uint    numBytes, //UintPtr numBytes,
    ACCESS_LEVEL accLevel);
```

when I execute it, there's an error of unbalanced stack.

Can somebody help me to figure out where the error is?

The marked part is what I have tried but it failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unbalanced Stack!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171790/unbalanced-stack)

Comment: PInvoke doesn't imbalance the stack, *you* imbalance the stack by not correctly pinvoking native methods by not declaring them correctly in managed code.  What is ACCESS_LEVEL on both sides?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Calling convention is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ code uses the `cdecl` calling convention but your p/invoke uses `stdcall`. Change or the other to match.

For example, you could change the p/invoke to use `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

The other comments I would make are:

- It may be preferable to use `extern "C"` to suppress C++ name mangling. Although in the comments, Hans argues for mangling.
- You've mapped `size_t` to `uint`. That will work fine on 32 bit, but not on 64 bit, where `size_t` is 64 bits wide. I suggest that you use `UIntPtr` here.
- Are you quite sure that the function calls SetLastError. It's not a Windows function so I'd guess it does not.

Comment: I change the calling convention from stdcall to cdecl, and it works.
And I also get to use UintPtr; the extern "C" is new to me, I need to figure out how to use it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dave - please don't recommend extern "C".  The mangling provides a very good diagnostic when the C++ programmer changes his function and the C# programmer has moved on.

Comment: @Hans I see your point. I find mangled names untidy, but that should not matter. Of course, exporting mangled names ties you to a specific compiler. Not much good if you want to support multiple compilers.