# c# dllimport wchar_t * to stringbuilder

Tags: c#, dllimport

what i have in hidapi.c library:

```
int HID_API_EXPORT HID_API_CALL testwchar(wchar_t * string) {
    //...
    wcsncpy(string, cur_dev->serial_number, wcslen(cur_dev->serial_number));
    return wcslen(cur_dev->serial_number);
}
```

what i have in c#:

```
[DllImport("hidapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern unsafe int testwchar(StringBuilder stringt);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
res = testwchar(sb);
```

i've missed some part of code in c function //... it enumerates devices  and searches by vid/pid and returns serial, it works fine when i tested it in testapi.cpp, but when i've tryed to write c# gui...visual studio 2012 raises error talking about imbalanced stack... as i understand if i use string as out parameter i need to use stringbuilder instead of string.

what am i doing wrong? thanx for any advice.

p.s. sorry, but formatting doe not worked, so code is a mess...

Comment: Post `HID_API_EXPORT` and `HID_API_CALL` definitions. Probably, the issue is about the wrong calling convention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unbalanced Stack!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171790/unbalanced-stack)

Comment: Don't write code like this.  How could testwchar() possibly guess how much space is available in the StringBuilder?  Guessing wrong corrupts the GC heap, extremely hard to diagnose.  Add another argument that says how big the buffer is.

Comment: #ifdef _WIN32
      #define HID_API_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
      #define HID_API_CALL
#else
      #define HID_API_EXPORT /**< API export macro */
      #define HID_API_CALL /**< API call macro */
#endif

#define HID_API_EXPORT_CALL HID_API_EXPORT HID_API_CALL /**< API export and call macro*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

Comment: StringBuilder lengths are known, usb-device uses 64,
i've not copypasted, i typed  simplifyed code, just an idea.

it's really strange,but previously i've tryed to add:
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
and it did not helped, but after reopening solution
all works fine... maybe some bug appeared,i think question may be closed, sorry for disturbance and thanx for all answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the hidapi functions yourself to compile the information you want. You can find documentation for them [here](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/hidapi/doxygen/html/group__API.html), rather than using this string function. It'll be far more efficient.

If you need poniters, the code on [this page](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) should help you.