# How to call a C function from C# with a WCHAR* in parameter?

Tags: c#, c, dll, import

I have the following C function

```
NTSTATUS
SendBuffer(
_In_ UINT32 Number,
_In_ PWCHAR wszBuffer
)
```

and the following c# method

```
[DllImport(@"cfunc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SendBuffer")]
    public static extern long SendBuffer(uint Number, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wszBuffer);
```

and in c# i try to call the function with

```
string buffer = "one two treee";
SendBuffer((uint)x, buffer);
```

But i receive an `System.AccessViolationException` when i run the program. How can i fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the `SendBuffer` function modify the string `wszBuffer`? If so, you need a `StringBuilder` not a `String`.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270525/sending-a-c-sharp-string-as-an-argument-to-a-unmanaged-c-dll-function

Comment: The C# return type `long` does not match the return type of the C function. Use the C# type `int` instead.

Answer (score -1):

A WChar is 16 bits so you need to send Uint16[].  See code below.

```
            string buffer = "one two treee";
            UInt16[] data = buffer.ToCharArray().Select(x => (UInt16)x).ToArray();
```