# Passing values and pointers between a c# and a c function

Tags: c#, c++, c

I am trying to use an open-source DLL to convert SQL queries between different dialects in a C# university project. I have a function in the dll which requires a void type pointer to an object. I cannot find a suitable type in c#  to use for calling this function.

I've tried using a IntPtr for the required pointer to the object but i am getting the following error

> A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsFormsApp1!WindowsFormsApp1.Form1::SetParserTypes' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

the function in c/c++ :

```
void SetParserTypes(void *parser, short source, short target)
{
    if(parser == NULL)
        return;

    SqlParser *sql_parser = (SqlParser*)parser;

    // Run conversion
    sql_parser->SetTypes(source, target);
}
```

the function im trying to use in c# :

```
[DllImport(dllName: "DLL_LOCATION", EntryPoint = "SetParserTypes")]
public unsafe static extern void SetParserTypes(void *parser , short source, short target);
```

i am calling this function like this :

```
SetParserTypes(&parserObj, 1,2);
```

I am getting the following exception when calling the function in c#

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsFormsApp1!WindowsFormsApp1.Form1::SetParserTypes' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'

Comment: I'd concentrate on the part that says *Check that the calling convention* matches. You don't indicate what calling convention you are using in your posted code.

Comment: where does parserObj come from?

Comment: Read the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506796/pinvokestackimbalance-how-can-i-fix-this-or-turn-it-off

Comment: i get the parserObj  from another function in the DLL. I am using IntPtr to store that object @JeffRSon

Comment: I don't get why that worked but it did. @TimurKukharskiy

Answer (score 1):

That's at least because of the type of your parameter `parser`, it should be declared as a `System.IntPtr` instead of `void*`.

For more information about type mapping between C# and C++ have a look to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke